# Silverlight: Not naming controls in XAML when using MVVM (Silverlight)?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light

Can anyone confirm if I am using MVVM (2 way binding) then I don't need to name my controls in XAML as I won't be accessing them via code behind but will be updating them by Binding?

This was the case with WPF but unsure whether Silverlight allows a control without `x:Name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to name your controls to use binding.
But you still can name them to aid in some UI scenarios (animations, drag&drop, etc).

Comment: +1 - pretty hard to use element binding without a control name :)

Comment: Element binding is only recommended in view-only bindings (for example a slider that might give the user the option to change the size of an image preview, no VM required for this). In all other cases, don't use element binding!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need them for View-ViewModel connection. However, names are **needed** i.e. when binding to other XAML elements (using `Binding ElementName=nameOfControl, Path=propertyOfControl`).